# Branch.io : how to remove deeplinking on Quick Links?

Tags: branch.io, fabric.io

I want to create Quick Links in Branch.io that redirect for example :
- either to my iOS list of app if the user is on iOS
- or to my Android list of app if the user is on Android

So I created a Quick Link in Branch.io.

In the "REDIRECTS" tab, I pasted my iOS url and Android url to my list of apps in the appropriate fields, and changes the type of these fiels to 'Web URL'.

My problem if that if the user has got my app on its device, it will open my app and not my catalog. It is because it is written on the 'REDIRECTS' page: 'If the app isn't installed, send users to: ...'

In my case, I want to send the users to my catalog even if the app is installed.

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the web instead of the app, please check out the web_only feature: https://docs.branch.io/pages/links/integrate/#open-web-instead-of-app